# flash upload control in javascript

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, flash

how to use a swf upload control in javascript for a page developed in asp.net & c#.net?
can any one provide the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Flash uploaders come with code snippets and instructions. [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) has a [full section](http://www.swfupload.org/project/asp_net) covering ASP.NET support - maybe that'll give you what you need.